# does visual studio 2013 work with team foundation server 2005?

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently using visual studio 2012.3 and I would like to upgrade to 2013.

only issue is, I must be able to connect to TFS 2005, i just need basic functionality like check out, check in, shelve. (I can do it with 2012)

can I do this with 2013?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this will not work. See the post below from Microsoft in regards to Visual Studio 2013 and issues connecting with Team Foundation Server 2008. Since they're saying that it is not compatible with TFS2008, I would think that it's safe to assume that even earlier versions of TFS would also not be supported.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800083/vs-2013-rc-to-tfs-2008

> **Posted by Microsoft on 9/13/2013 at 1:13 PM**
>
> Thanks for reaching out to us about the issues that you've experienced while trying to connect to a TFS 2008 server from VS 2013 RC. For the VS 2013 release, we no longer support TFS 2008, and the symptoms that you are seeing are the result of this lack of support. To work around this issue, you can use either VS 2012 (which can be installed on the same machine side-by-side with VS 2013) or upgrade the TFS 2008 server to a supported version (i.e. TFS 2010 or higher).